# How can I bind dynamically "this" for each function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dynamic, this

I'm looking for a way to bind `this` to each `function`.

I've tried also to create a execution context (wrapper); this doesn't work for included scripts/templates with `<script>`-Tags

Here are examples of my want..

Examples:

```
//Added "this" to each function: "this_"

//Inside <script src='external_source_link'></script>

function a() { alert(this) }
a(); //result: "this_"
```

I need a way to dynamically detect any function created. Before this happens (the creation of a function) I should have a possibility to add something to a function or function body (parameters and arguments)

```
function a() { } //my dynamically manipulation: a = a.bind("this_");
```

This can't be a wrapper `{ }` because im also loading scripts from external resource with `<script>`-Tags

```
<script src="external_source_link"></script>
```

So maybe there's a solution with the manipultion of `Funtion.prototype`...

Comment: So you want to bind literally every new function to a particular context? Is this only for global functions or every function ever?

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem, there shouldn't be any reason to do something like this ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure doing this will create a lot more problems than what you're trying to solve with this approach.

Comment: ... for every function everywhere in an included script ... @Siguza i try to change an item from every non-global-scope like (function () { (function () { alert(this) } }

Comment: @methosiea But why??? That's the question

Comment: Usually people ask a question, and omit what they've tried... I feel like in this case, what you're really telling us is what you've tried, but we need to know what the exact problem you're facing is! There is likely a different and more effective way of designing a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand well you need a `proxy` for `this`.

If you want that you can do it this way:

```
function caller(){

    proxy(this,callee, "hello");

}
function callee(testStr){
    console.log("this: ", this);

    console.log("testStr: ", testStr);
}

function proxy(thisToBind, fnToCall){
    var args = arguments;
    if (args.length > 2) {
        delete args[0];
        delete args[1];
    }
    else {
        args = undefined;
    }
    fnToCall.call(thisToBind, args);
}

caller();
```

If you want to overwrite the original `Function.prototype.constructor` globally (for all functions) i'm afraid you cannot. However check out the [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)